# Overlaying frame number with ffmpeg

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

This should be simple but it is giving me fits and I haven't been able to find this specific problem.  I am trying to overlay the frame number on a set of videos but my ffmpeg command string is ignoring any text overlay that has anything to do with a frame number.  For example, these produce the correct overlay

```
"-vf drawtext=fontfile='Arial.ttf': text='TEST': fontsize=30: fontcolor=yellow@1.0:x=(w-text_w-15):y=15" 
"-vf drawtext=fontfile='Arial.ttf': text='%camera%': fontsize=30: fontcolor=yellow@1.0:x=(w-text_w-15):y=15" 
"-vf drawtext=fontfile='Arial.ttf': text='%vname%': fontsize=30: fontcolor=yellow@1.0:x=(w-text_w-15):y=15"
```

but these all ignore the "text" input and instead overlay "fontsize=30" or "start_number=1" to the frames

```
"-vf drawtext=fontfile='Arial.ttf': text=%{n}: fontsize=30: fontcolor=yellow@1.0:x=(w-text_w-15):y=15" 
"-vf drawtext=fontfile='Arial.ttf': text='%{n}': fontsize=30: fontcolor=yellow@1.0:x=(w-text_w-15):y=15" 
"-vf drawtext=fontfile='Arial.ttf': text='Frame %{frame_num}': start_number=1: fontsize=30: fontcolor=yellow@1.0:x=(w-text_w-15):y=15"
```

I am at a loss as to why it is not properly identifying or using the frame number.

I have tried multiple variations such as those shown above including swapping the order of the inputs to no effect.

Comment: In a batch file, the percent symbol is a special character used to reference an environmental  variable. If you need to use a literal percent symbol it must be escaped by doubling the percent symbol.

Comment: Apologies if the duplicate question seems like it cannot be a duplicate, but as per the comment above, the answer does cover it.